# When does the direct image functor respect direct sums of sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, adjoint-functors, coherent-sheaves

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes, where $Y = \text{spec}A$ is affine. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. Is it true that the direct image functor $f_{*}$ respects arbitrary direct sums in the sense that,
$$
f_{*} \bigoplus_{d \geq 0} \mathcal{L}^{\otimes d} \simeq \bigoplus_{d \geq 0} f_{*} \mathcal{L}^{\otimes d} 
$$

Are there any conditions on $f$ that would make this true?

Comment: This is always true.

Comment: Great, thank you! I was hoping it was. But is there a simple way to prove it?

Comment: The key point is just to prove that $f_* (F\oplus G) \cong f_*(F)\oplus f_*(G)$, and the rest follows by standard induction arguments, no? And to prove the key point, note that $f_* (F\oplus G)(U) = (F\oplus G)(f^{-1}(U)) \cong F(f^{-1}(U))\oplus G(f^{-1}(U)) = f_*(F)(U)\oplus f_*(G)(U)$. On any open set.

Comment: @TabesBridges that would definitely work for the finite direct sum case, but surely that doesn't work for infinite?

Comment: @Luke what aspect of the argument bothers you? My feeling is that this should just follow from "right adjoints preserve limits" since $\oplus$ is both direct sum and direct product in $Sh(X)$, but again maybe there is something about the infinite case that I am missing? Alternatively, how do you feel about the statement "restriction of scalars preserves direct sums"? Since your base is affine perhaps this will do the job.

Comment: @TabesBridges But direct sums are only direct products in the finite case aren't they? In an abelian category infinite direct sums are certainly not direct products in general.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to believe this is true. Even when we are talking about affine morphisms. If somebody could provide a proof, I'd be happy. But I have never seen one.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, there is a proof that direct images along quasi-compact, quasi-separated morphisms commute with directed colimits in \[Stacks, [Tag 07TB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07TB)\], which reduces to \[Stacks, [Tag 01FF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01FF)\]. Théorème 4.12.1 in Godement's book is another reference for this latter result.

Comment: Note that direct sums are not directed colimits, but you can still apply these results since arbitrary direct sums are directed colimits of finite ones; see [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/120847/33088).

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Yes. I believe this argument is correct. It basically boils down to the fact that directed colimits commute with the global section functor under appropriate finiteness conditions. I apologize to the OP for my glibness.

Comment: That is fine for the case where $f$ is quasicompact and quasiseparated. But my entire concern was that it seems to claim it works for arbitrary $f$.

Comment: In general, if $f$ is not quasi-compact, $f_*$ does not preserve infinite direct sums, you can easily construct counter-example on a scheme with an infinite number of connected components. I do not have a counter-example of the form $\bigoplus \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ though.

Comment: In general, $f_*$ does not preserve infinite direct sums. Exercise 10.18 of Algebraic Geometry by Ulrich Gortz and Torsten Wedhorn gives a counterexample. (Also by the proposition 10.30 of this book.)